# displaying lightbox image after click on google map marker

Tags: javascript, flash, maps, lightbox

I have HTML code

```
<a href="clouds.swf" class="bump">clouds</a>
```

and a marker with this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker01, 'click', function() {
    window.location = "pano/pano02.swf";
});
```

When I click on link in HTML code, it displays `pano02.swf` as bumpbox image (lightbox alternative), but when I click on google map marker, it opens a new window with flash animation.

How to display it as bumpbox by clicking on google map marker? Thank you very much!

Comment: How is "bumpbox" initialized?

Comment: Hi Niklas, its initialized by .bump class   '<script type="text/javascript"> doBump('.bump'); </script>'